# Radio buttons: Replacing the stock round ones with built in android buttons

Tags: android

How do I create a group of *radio buttons where the buttons look like nice stock android buttons*?

This is what I have found so far:

The look of a radio button can be replaced with 4 drawables.There is an example of this on the web.

---

This does not work for me. So I have figured out two bad choices:

(A) Use stock buttons -do the radio logic in java. *Gross.*

(B) Render the buttons to drawables set them at runtime. *Blah*

Any ideas are very appreciated.

(This is my first question here. Hope it is well formulated.)

Answer (score 2):

Use RadioButton and specify `android:button="@drawable/mybutton"`, where res/drawable/mybuton.xml contains a custom `<selector>`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

This is actually the original [selector for RadioButton](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable/btn_radio.xml).

Comment: Exactly what I need. I have my buttons working. Thanks so much.